# Fixed point of a differentiable function on a closed interval

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Given a differentiable function $h:[0,3]\to [0,3]$ such that $h(0)=1 h(1)=2, h(3)=2$.

(a) Argue that there exists a point $d ∈ [0,3]$ where $h(d)=d$.

(b) Argue that at some point c we have $h'(c)=1/3$.

(c) Argue that $h'(x)=1/4$ at some point in the domain.

I think I understand b and c, as by the mean value theorem I get that I can find $c\in (0,1) $ for which $h'(c)=1$ and similarly $d\in (1,3)$ for which $h'(d) =0$, and then using the intermediate value property find the desired values.

But I'm not sure how to approach (a), it feels like continuity should be enough to prove it but I can't see how, and not sure how difderentiability helps me.

Comment: @GitGud Oh oops, fixed

Comment: You can apply IVT to the derivatives if you know that $h'(x)$ is continuous.

Comment: For (a), try applying IVT to the function $f(x)=h(x)-x$.

Comment: @cantorhead, oh well that makes it easy. Thanks!